# Dropdown SelectedValue changes unrelated properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

```
 drpDwnLstBillContact.SelectedValue = billContactId.ToString();
 drpDwnLstRegContact.SelectedValue = regContactId.ToString();
 drpDwnLstTechContact.SelectedValue = techContactId.ToString();
```

I am trying to set dropdowns' selectedvalue property, but I have a problem.

The values of variables are:

```
billContactId=786867;
regContactId=3487347;
techContactId=37463;
```

The problem is on the first line. `billContactId` is assigned to selectedvalue property of drpDwnLstBillContact, also on the second line regContactId is assigned to drpDwnLstRegContact's selectedvalue property. But when it is assigned to it the first dropdown's (drpDwnLstBillContact), selected value is also set to regContactId too.  Why that second line of code effects the first line?

Comment: Are there any handlers or dependency between them ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible until somewhere else you are setting the value again. Try going through your code once.

Comment: One thing more, are you sure first dropdown's selected value is correct for the first time? Did you debug the code?

Comment: @V4Vendetta they have selectedindexchanged event handlers but they are not fired when I assign the  values. I have placed breakpoints to that events.

Comment: @asma yes I am sure I am debugging and after the first dropdown's value set it is correct but after set second dropdown's attribute the first dropdown's attribute is set to that value too.

Comment: can you post aspx code of these ddls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution.

In the FillDropDowns method I have created only one ListItem and added it to each dropdown, so when I change the dropdowns selectedvalue property it changes the list item and all of dropdowns' listitem change too. Now I have created seperate ListItem objects for each dropdown and problem is solved.

**Old Code**

```
 foreach (string[] contactData in data)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(contactData[0], contactData[1]);

            drpDwnLstRegContact.Items.Add(li);
            drpDwnLstTechContact.Items.Add(li);
            drpDwnLstBillContact.Items.Add(li);
        }
```

**New Code**

```
 foreach (string[] contactData in data)
        {
            ListItem li = new ListItem(contactData[0], contactData[1]);
            ListItem li1 = new ListItem(contactData[0], contactData[1]);
            ListItem li2 = new ListItem(contactData[0], contactData[1]);
            drpDwnLstRegContact.Items.Add(li);
            drpDwnLstTechContact.Items.Add(li1);
            drpDwnLstBillContact.Items.Add(li2);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't affect the first; drop down lists are atomic and I've never heard of this issue before.  Are you sure somewhere else in code the control isn't being reassigned to a different value?

Answer (score 1):

I cant clearly get what's the problem. However I guess you are filling your `DropDownList` on every `Page.Load` event which makes the first item always selected.

Try the following on `Page.Load` handler:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    FillDropDownList();
}
```

Comment: I am filling them on gridview's selectedrowchanged event, and after filling I am setting their selectedvalue properties.

Answer (score 1):

This can help. (Don't ask why...)

```
drpDwnLstBillContact.SelectedIndex = -1;
drpDwnLstBillContact.SelectedIndex = 
    drpDwnLstBillContact.Items.IndexOf(drpDwnLstBillContact.Items.
        FindByValue(billContactId.ToString()));

drpDwnLstRegContact.SelectedIndex = -1;
drpDwnLstRegContact.SelectedIndex = 
    drpDwnLstRegContact.Items.IndexOf(drpDwnLstRegContact.Items.
        FindByValue(regContactId.ToString()));

drpDwnLstTechContact.SelectedIndex = -1;
drpDwnLstTechContact.SelectedIndex = 
    drpDwnLstTechContact.Items.IndexOf(drpDwnLstTechContact.Items.
        FindByValue(techContactId.ToString()));
```